# window.getSelection() not working in ios6 device?

Tags: javascript, ios6, safari

In my application i used java script to get selected text.this will be work perfectly in simulator but ios6 device return null string.

```
var select = window.getSelection();
var selObj = select.toString()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [How to captured Selected Text Range in iOS after text selection expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300590/how-to-captured-selected-text-range-in-ios-after-text-selection-expansion). It's very thorough and the answer has a working jsfiddle (which should be able to answer your question).

This answer seems to answer and go beyond your question (as well as address another possible issue you might find).