# Show custom menu on text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I want to have a ability to show the custom menu (or context menu) when a user selects some text much simillar to what medium provides.

[image: context menu]

How do implement this something like this? I am aware of native/jquery context menu plugins, but how do I know when the user selects the text? [Browser's **onselect**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp) seems to be supported only on input elements.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `window.getSelection()`? You could write your own listener for it, and the `selectionchange` event is supported on IE and Chrome/Safari (though not Firefox or Opera)

Comment: for not supported browsers u can add selection check via setInterval (its bad for perfomance, but will fix)

Answer (score 20):

Here is a pretty basic listener for `.getSelection()`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YstZn/500/)**

```
if (!window.x) 
{
    x = {};
}

x.Selector = {};
x.Selector.getSelected = function() 
{
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) 
    {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } 
    else if (document.getSelection) 
    {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } 
    else if (document.selection) 
    {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function() 
    {
        var selectedText = x.Selector.getSelected();
        if(selectedText != '')
        {
            alert(selectedText);
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of an alert, simply make your popup/toolbar visible. Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
I changed the demo to show one possible way to show the popup menu/toolbar.

Comment: better to use event selectionchange, but for unsupported browsers use other events: mouseup, drugend, touch, keyup (for shift+right and other keyboard methods of selection modifications, but only for unsupported browsers )

Comment: See the above comment

Comment: @Abhishek Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300590/how-to-captured-selected-text-range-in-ios-after-text-selection-expansion