# Web mobile selections

Tags: javascript, mobile, selection

On mobile browser I'd like to get the actual selection but `window.getSelection()` seems always to be empty.

Is there a way of getting selections on a mobile browser?

Comment: check out the answer here with the fiddle:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300590/how-to-captured-selected-text-range-in-ios-after-text-selection-expansion

Comment: Thank you, I really got stuck with this issue! :)